# Passing data to Vertex shader does not work?

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer, vertex-shader

How OpenGL really works, is still a big mystery. Today I started with Framebuffers. In my framebuffer I want to pass data to my vertex shader. The following code is a part of it:

**Initialization**

```
(...) // Compile and link shaderProgram
(...) // Compile and link lightingShaderProgram
glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
(...) // Setting up the map and objects VAO's
if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    return false;
}
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAORectLighting);
glBindVertexArray(VAORectLighting);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBOQuadLighting);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOQuadLighting);
        GLfloat test[] = {0.5f, 0.5f};
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(test), test, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        // For the last two arguments, 2*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0 give the same result
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glUseProgram(lightingShaderProgram);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(lightingShaderProgram, "texFramebuffer"), 0);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
glGenTextures(1, &frameBufferTexture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameBufferTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, viewportWidth, viewportHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameBufferTexture, 0);
```

**Render loop**

```
(...)

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    (...) // Using subDataBuffer to update the scene
    glBindVertexArray(m->VAOMap);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, m->mapDrawIndex);
    glBindVertexArray(m->VAOObjects);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, m->objectsDrawIndex);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glUseProgram(lightingShaderProgram);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glBindVertexArray(VAORectLighting);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameBufferTexture);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 6);
glBindVertexArray(0);

glfwSwapBuffers(window);

(...)
```

**Vertex Shader source**

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0 in vec2 lightpos;
out VSO
{
    vec4 vLight;
} outputs;
void main()
{
    outputs.vLight = vec4(lightpos.x, lightpos.y, 0.5, 0.5);
}
```

The rest is not relevant. Everything works, if I fill in custom values for lightpos.x and lightpos.y in the source code of the Vertex shader, I see the correct result.

However, what does **not** work is: Using `(lightpos.x == 0 ? 0.5 : -0.5)` I could debug the value of `lightpos`, and it turned out **both values are zero**. But lightpos should definitely be `0.5` and `0.5`!

After extensive debugging (trial and error), I found something very peculiar. The following code returns two zeroes for `lightpos.xy`.

```
GLfloat test[] = {0.5f, 0.5f};
```

However, the following code returns `0.3`, `0.2` for `lightpos.xy`:

```
GLfloat test[] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 0.2f};
```

And if I add more values to `test`:

```
GLfloat test[] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 0.2f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, ...};
```

The values received by the vertex shader will always be the 10th and 11th index of `test`, no matter what I do.

My question now obviously is, why?! What am I missing?

My suspicions are the following (but I have no idea what it means, and how to deal with this):

> When a non-zero buffer object is bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target, the vertex array pointer parameter is interpreted as an offset within the buffer object measured in basic machine units.

Source: [OpenGL.org docs: glBindBuffer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml)

In addition, `VAORectLighting` has the value `3`, and `VBOQuadLighting` has the value `7`, this adds up to `10`. But I still don't see how this works.

Comment: Because you're drawing 6 vertices, and each vertex has its own lightpos value (becuase it's a vertex attribute)?

Comment: Interesting thought :) But the 6 vertices are emitted by my geometry shader using `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, so I expect I only send one vertex in, right? (and how does that add up to 10?) Also, see my edit, maybe that's a clue.

Comment: `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 6);` This will submit 6 point primitives to the geometry shader, but you only have two light attributes. The number of primitives that your geometry shader actually emits is irrelevant to this call.

Comment: Wow thanks! I only had to change `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 6)` to `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1)`, and it works like it should. If you create an answer for it, I will accept it. Basically, my understanding of `glDrawArrays` was wrong, I thought the buffer requests the shader program to draw stuff, and `glDrawArrays` simply draws (part of) the result. But it is actually the other way around, the `glDrawArrays` requests the shader program to draw something. Thanks for that realisation!